# How can I formulate 8-Puzzle for SA algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, simulated-annealing, sliding-tile-puzzle

How can I formulate the 8-puzzle problem for solving with the Simulated Annealing algorithm?

I've think a lot about that but I couldn't find a solution!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume by 8-puzzle you mean something like [this](http://mypuzzle.org/sliding). The only thing that seems at all tricky is finding some way of describing the energy (the distance of the state from the solved state solved).  You must have the solved state have the lowest energy in the system, and it is nice to have states that are almost solved have low energy.  A plausible energy would be the total distance of all the tiles from their solved position.  In other words the number of moves it would take to solve the puzzle if we were not restricted to only one tile per cell.  Another plausible energy would be the number of tiles out of place.